# Python - Get value from pandas dataframe by index condition

Tags: python, pandas

I want to get an element out of a dataframe by a condition, like this:

```
elem = df[(df['id']==enum['properties']['property2']) & (df['time']==10)].col3
```

Since it's impossible for Python to know if this will return just one or a bunch of rows, it returns this as

```
6244    52.45
Name: col3, dtype: float64
```

But I know there's only going to be one element like this. How can I make it so that `elem` only contains `52.45`?

**EDIT**

The answer by Julien Marrec works fine in a single line, but not in the following loop:

```
for enum in data['features']:
    elem = df[(df['id']==enum['properties']['property2']) & (df['time']==10)].col3.values[0]
```

It gives me an `IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0.`

Comment: If you're after the scalar value then `elem.values[0]` will give you that or just `elem[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do a quick hack:

```
elem.values[0]
```

Update: after the edit to your question, you need to test if there's actually an element to return or if the series is empty:

```
for enum in data['features']:
    elem = df[(df['id']==enum['properties']['property2']) & (df['time']==10)].col3
    if len(elem) == 1:
        return elem.values[0]
```

Comment: Thanks, this works as a single line, but not in a loop. I'll edit the question!

Comment: Updated the question.